# Error when running localstack in kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, localstack

I've installed localstack using Helm:

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/localstack/localstack

The localstack chart was installed in its own localstack namespace, and I saw no errors in the localstack pod logs. In a different namespace I have a Spring Boot app (version 3.2.1), that needs to communicate with SQS in localstack. Here's the Sqs service:

```
package com.myapp.gateway.common;

import com.myapp.gateway.config.ConfigProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.SqsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.ListQueuesRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.ListQueuesResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException;

import java.net.URI;

@Service
public class SqsService {

    private final SqsClient sqsClient;
    private final ConfigProperties configProperties;

    public SqsService(ConfigProperties configProperties) {
        this.configProperties = configProperties;
        this.sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
            .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localstack.localstack.svc.cluster.local"))
            .region(Region.of(configProperties.awsRegion()))
            .build();
}

public void listQueues() {

    System.out.println("\nList Queues:");

    try {
        ListQueuesRequest listQueuesRequest = ListQueuesRequest.builder().build();
        ListQueuesResponse listQueuesResponse = sqsClient.listQueues(listQueuesRequest);

        for (String url : listQueuesResponse.queueUrls()) {
            System.out.println("Queue url: " + url);
        }

    } catch (SqsException e) {
        System.err.println(
                "SqsException: "
                        + "getMessage: "
                        + e.getMessage()
                        + " | sdkHttpResponse.statusCode: "
                        + e.awsErrorDetails().sdkHttpResponse().statusCode()
                        + " | sdkHttpResponse.statusText: "
                        + e.awsErrorDetails().sdkHttpResponse().statusText()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, I'm using the localstack service FQDN, but my service logs show the following:

```
List Queues:
SqsException: getMessage: Service returned HTTP status code 403 (Service: Sqs, Status Code: 
403, Request ID: null) | sdkHttpResponse.statusCode: 403 | sdkHttpResponse.statusText: 
Optional[connecting to localstack.localstack.svc.cluster.local:80: resolving host 
localstack.localstack.svc.cluster.local: lookup localstack.localstack.svc.cluster.local: no 
such host]
```

It is not clear why this is happening, because when I kubectl exec into my service container and run:

```
nc -zv localstack.localstack.svc.cluster.local 80
```

I get:

```
localstack.localstack.svc.cluster.local (10.104.143.32:80) open
```

Port 4566 is also open but it doesn't work either.
What is the correct endpoint URL?

Comment: Are you able to connect from local host through port forward ? Also `4566` seem to be the pod port, but are you sure the service is exposing it through port `80` or `4566` ?

Comment: @Yann39 I tried replacing the url with `http://localhost:4566` along with running `kubectl port-forward -n localstack service/localstack 4566:4566` in a different linux screen. It says `Connect to localhost:4566 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused`, so still no luck. I need to access the localstack from inside my service.

Comment: @Yann39 running `nc -zv localhost 4566` from outside the cluster after port forwarding says connection is open, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I just installed it (`helm repo add localstack https://helm.localstack.cloud` & `helm install my-localstack localstack/localstack --version 0.6.9`), then port forwarded to local host (`kubectl port-forward -n default svc/my-release-localstack 4566:4566`) and it works fine reaching http://localhost:4566. I also installed another pod (i.e. tomcat via `helm install my-release oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/tomcat
`  and I can also reach my-release-localstack on port 4566 from there (`echo >/dev/tcp/my-release-localstack/4566) &>/dev/null && echo "open" || echo "closed"` outputs "open")

Comment: I can also reach it from another pod in another namespace (i.e. `nc -zv my-release-localstack.default.svc.cluster.local 4566` successfully returns "Connected to 10.43.166.63:4566". So there should be something on your side.